# VS2010 custom tool - generated filename bug? (YUI Custom Tool and others)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, customtool

I don't know if this is a bug of visual studio 2010 but when I run the YUI Custom Tool in some files I get the new file with a "1" added to the filename..

For example, I have a file named Flexigrid.js and when I run the custom tool I get a file called Flexigrid1.min.js instead of Flexigrid.min.js

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel over Windows 7 Proffesional 64bit...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!

Cheers from Argentina!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

1) Unload the .csproj open it for edit..
2) Find the files and remove the .. tag. Example:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="JavaScript\flexigrid.js">
  <Generator>YUICustomTool</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>flexigrid1.min.js</LastGenOutput> <!-- Remove this tag -->
</EmbeddedResource>
```

3) Remove the minified file reference (e.g: flexigrid1.min.js). Example:

```
<!-- Remove -->
<EmbeddedResource Include="JavaScript\flexigrid1.min.js">
   <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
   <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
   <DependentUpon>flexigrid.js</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
<!-- Remove -->
```

4) Save and reload the project.
5) Run custom tool again... this time should generate flexigrid.min.js

I hope it helps...

Cheers!